# How to add vertical space between UINavigationBar and UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm working with my UI completely programmatically here. When I add a `UISegmentedControl` to my `UITableViewController`'s `header view`, it just fixes itself up there with no vertical space between the `UINavigationBar`. How can I add some padding between the `UISegmentedControl` and the `UINavigationBar` ?

Comment: Modifying frame of the segmented control has no effect ?

Comment: I was wondering if I could modify the `header view` property somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate a `UIView` object and add your `UISegmentedControl` as a subview. Then set the `UIView` as your table's `headerView`. You'll be able to add padding by adjusting the frame of the `UIView` you created.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 150 /* <-- adjust this value for more or less padding */)];

    UISegmentedControl *segControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"One", @"Two", @"Three"]];
    segControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 90, 200, 29);

    //calculate the middle of the header view
    CGFloat middleOfView = headerView.bounds.size.width / 2;
    CGFloat middleOfSegControl = segControl.bounds.size.width / 2;
    CGFloat middle = middleOfView - middleOfSegControl;

    //position the seg control in the middle
    CGRect frame = segControl.frame;
    frame.origin.x = middle;
    segControl.frame = frame;

    [headerView addSubview:segControl];

    self.theTableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
}
```

Of course you can mess with the frames some more to get things positioned like you want them.